# How To Stop A Leak In A Refrigerator Water Line

Tags: plumbing

Our original refrigerator had an ice maker.  They installed a white plastic type of water line going from under our kitchen sink, through our kitchen cabinets and behind the refrigerator.

We had to get another refrigerator a year or two ago.  It has no ice maker or water in the door.

When they took out the old fridge and put in the new one, they capped some thing off from under our kitchen sink and then behind the new fridge they put a cuppling or something like that to cap off the end of the water line behind the fridge and it just lays on the floor.

Recently we noticed water behind the fridge.  The plastic water line has a hole or crack in it.  It is leaking out water.

What do we need to do??

Comment: We tried putting electrical tape around the hole/crack in the water line, however, it still leaks out water.

Comment: We tried shutting/turning off the hot and cold water valves under our kitchen sink and water still leaks out from the water line.

Comment: Not sure how to tell if the t type valve under the sink if it is turned off or not.  It is easy to turn.  They have the t type looking valve turned side ways under the sink.

Comment: Does the cold side of the faucet drip when the valve is turned to the "off" position? If so, this is an opportunity to change the entire shutoff.

Comment: What did they cap off under the sink and where and how is this line attached to your plumbing system. Be sure to describe valves and whether they are before or after the connection. Photos will help.

Comment: Some photos might be helpful. specifically a photo of the valve under the sink and/or the attachment point of the pipe to the plumbing system, as well as the damage to the pipe and the cap at the end of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

There a countless ways that the fridge line could have been installed. A photo of under the sink would greatly help, in particular showing the connection to the water supply.

Can you see where the fridge line connects to the water supply? Is it connected to the same supply that feeds the sink? If so, even with the isolation valves shut under the sink, there will still be pressure in the fridge line. If you open the sink's faucet, you can confirm that water is off, additionally this will relieve the pressure in the fridge's line.

Sometimes a small valve is installed on the fridge line under the sink. It could have been bumped open.

You'll need to determine how it is connected before you can fix it.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Thanks for this information pdd.  Under our kitchen sink there is 2 valves that work the cold and hot water for the sink.  The fridge water line is a clear white plastic tube.  The fridge water line goes from under our kitchen sink and through our bottom kitchen cabinets and they made a small hole to allow the water line to come out of the side of the cabinet and to go behind our fridge.  Since our replacement fridge does not have an ice maker we no longer need the fridge line but it is leaking water.  It has a small hole or crack in the line.

Comment: There is a t valve under the sink.  Not sure which way turns it off so we can make sure no more water gets in to the unused fridge line.  The t valve is on it's side and looks like they put some type of clamp on the kitchen sink water area to block off the fridge line.  Still water in the fridge line though.  We have to empty buckets a couple times a day.  Any ideas?  Any help?  Can we take out the fridge line or would we have

Comment: Sorry.  I don't have a way to post photo's.

Answer (score -1):

Cut the line before it leaves the cabinet and then cap it.

Comment: There is a cap or some type of plug at the or on the end of the clear white plastic water line that is behind our fridge.  I thought about cutting some of the clear white plastic line off that is above where the hole is on the line and then putting the cap on there.  Would that work?  Does the cap just pull out/off of the end and then would it be easy to put the cap back on into where I cut it off?

Comment: Thanks Mcarrubba.  How do I cap it?  There is some type of plug on the end of the line that just lays behind our fridge.  Do I just pull the plug/cap out/off and then push it in to the new area where I cut the line above the hole/leak?  Should I turn off the water to the house as I know water is in the line?